# Is the cut locus geodesic?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $P$ be a point on compact Riemannian manifold $M$.  Let $L$ be the cut locus.  Let $Q$ be a smooth point of $L$.  Is $L$ totally geodesic in a neighborhood of $Q$?

Comment: The cut locus is in general not a submanifold. How do you define "totally geodesic"?